# PowerShell script to run the most recent .jar

Tags: powershell

I'm hosting a Minecraft Forge server, and I want to know if is possible for a Powershell script to dynamically run the latest forge .jar executable present in the server folder.

For reference, the forge jar uses this kind of filename:

```
forge-1.11.2-13.20.0.2314-universal.jar
```

with the `1.11.2-13.20.0.2314` part of its name varying according to the Forge and Minecraft version (values always crescent).

So, given I have several `forge-x.x.x-x.x.x-universal.jar` in the folder and I want to execute the most recent version, is possible to do this automatically in PS?

Comment: Yes. Sort by name or date and get the latest file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is simply "Yes". The real question should be how. If you do not have any background in Powershell, the code to do this would likely need a tweak or two along the line at some point.

Some basic Powershell:

```
$filename = "forge-1.11.2-13.20.0.2314-universal.jar"
$peices = $filename.Split("-")
```

Now you have an array of items about your file, split via the "-" char.

```
$mcVersion = $pieces[1]
$forgeVerion = $pieces[2]
```

Now you have variables that have the version numbers that you are concerned with.

The only thing left to do is to use `Get-ChildItem` to pull a list of the files, possibly with a `-Filter .jar` and use `ForEach-Object` to loop through them all.